# EXTJS Values between windows

Tags: javascript, function, extjs

to modify an Item, I call a function that shows me a modal window, I give to this function the value to change, and I want that after closing the modifiying window, return the value to the first one.
how to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide some code. Access your parent window this way :

```
var parentWin = Ext.getCmp('parent_window_id');
```

If parent window has a function say **callMeNow(value)** to pass the value you want after closing, then call it when child window is closed this way:

```
var childWin = Ext.getCmp('child_window_id');

childWin.on('beforeclose', function(){
    parentWin.callMeNow(valueToBePassed);
}, this);
```

Comment: I just used the beforeclose
thnx dude !!